# Flutter TextField disabled with border

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When I use the TextField Widget with `enabled` parameter set to`false`, the border disappears.

```dart
     Flexible(
          child: 
           TextField(
                  onTap: () {
                Future<DateTime> dateTime = _buildDataHoraInicial(context);
                dateTime.then((date){
                    _dataHoraInicial = date;
                    _dataTempoInicialController.text = date.toIso8601String();
                    print(_dataHoraInicial);
                });
              },
              controller: _dataTempoInicialController,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xfff7b733))),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.calendar_today,
                    color: Color(0xfff7b733),
                    size: 16.0,
                  ),
                  suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.access_time,
                      color: Color(0xfff7b733), size: 16.0),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xfff7b733))),
                  labelText: 'Data e Hora de Início',
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0, color: const Color(0xfff7b733))),
            ),
          ),
```

[image of the TextField Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMMIj.png)

How can I use TextField Widget with `enabled` parameter set to `true` keeping the border?

Answer (score 7):

To solve this problem I added the `disabledBorder` parameter from the `InputDecoration` and set it to `OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xfff7b733)))`

Answer (score 2):

do sumething like this:

```
TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Write your address",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.transparent)),
                    disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.transparent)),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.transparent)),
                    errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.transparent)),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.transparent)),
                    focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.transparent)),

          ),
     ),
),
```